# Wordpress function is_user_logged_in() always return true in Google Chrome

Tags: php, wordpress, google-chrome, authentication

I'm having a strange issue here with Wordpress. When I'm logged out, Wordpress still thinks I'm logged in. It displays user bar and logout button in sidebar widget (instead of log in button). When I try to enter admin panel however, Wordpress ask me to log in. So I'm logged out for sure. And this issue is only present in Chrome browser. I have no idea what could cause it. I disabled all plugins
I have some code in my theme that chekces if user is logged in and in Chrome this is always true.

Comment: Check when you logout is the cookie `wordpress_logged_in_*` still exists? Make sure you clear your browser cache as well.

Comment: @Rahil Wazir: Thanks for tip. Eventually the problem disappeared after reinstalling Chrome. That must have been a cookie or browser version issue.